# Mongo Query to retrieve documents having redundant values within an Array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

In my mongo db collection , I have few documents as below :
Each Document has a 'Bricks' array .

- In the Bricks Array , some documents have same 'brick_id' ( see - Document 1)
- Some documents have unique 'brick_id' ( see - Document 2)

Now, My Question is that I need to write a Mongo Query to retrieve all the Documents which contains redundant 'brick_id' in the "bricks" array .

Means , I need to get **Document 1** as output

Please help . I'm new to Mongo Db

```
**Document 1** :
{
  "_id" : 123 ,
  "page" : "new_page_1" ,
   "bricks" : [
      {
         "brick_id" : 160,
         "name" : "dev-br" 
      },
      {
          "brick_id" : 160,
          "name" : "dev-br2" 
      }
   ]
}

**Document 2**

{
  "_id" : 150 ,
  "page" : "new_page_1" ,
   "bricks" : [
      {
         "brick_id" : 200,
         "name" : "dev-br" 
      },
      {
          "brick_id" : 201,
          "name" : "dev-br2" 
      }
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might use the `$setUnion` operator to join `"$bricks.brick_id"` with an empty array, and compare its `$size` with that of the unmodified `"$bricks.brick_id"` array.  If the sizes are not equal, there was at least one duplicate.

Comment: Can you please help me with the query ? I understood your logic , but i'm new to Mongo query syntax